# Do humanoid undead or constructs have a soul for Magic Jar?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

*Magic Jar* states:

> You can attempt to possess any humanoid within 100 feet of you that you can see ... The target must make a Charisma saving throw. On a failure, your soul moves into the target's body, and the target's soul becomes trapped in the container.

How does this apply to creatures that do not have a soul, such as undead and constructs, which are animated by magic? Does the spell fail to possess such a creature? Or does the animation magic get captured in the container as a substitute "soul"?

Comment: related: [Does a simulacrum have a soul?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115682)

Comment: Is it established that undead have no soul by default? I get mindless skeletons not having them, but what about mummies/vampires/etc?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's irrelevant: *humanoid* is a type of creature (see the first chapter of the Monster Manual). *Undead* and *constructs* are **different** types and are ineligible targets. As are *giants*, *dragons*, etc.

In short, if it doesn't say *humanoid* in the monster stat block immediately under the name you can't cast *Magic Jar* on them.

Just in case it comes up: a Druid currently wildshaped is a *beast* or *elemental*, not a *humanoid*. Similarly, any creature under a *Polymorph* effect has the type they have been polymorphed into. So you can *Polymorph* the vampire to a *humanoid* and then *Magic Jar* them.